# How to forward serial devices' input to X?

Tags: xorg, serial-port

We have a barcode scanner used here, which for some reason has to be a serial device. So all its scanning output is sent to /dev/ttyACM0. If I `cat /dev/ttyACM0`, I could get the strings.

Problem now is, how to let these input be sent to X, acting like a normal keyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used softwedge but there are alternatives, Ubuntu provides some information around the topic at the following url.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BarcodeReaders

Comment: Nice. I am looking into the document. But the link in the document to softwedge gave me a 404.

Comment: Softwedge is found here: https://github.com/theatrus/softwedge